# Docker | Error by creation a Docker Image in Azure DevOps with VS 2019

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2019

I am new in the Docker-World and i struggle very hard to create a Docker Image in Azure DevOps.

So First i created a Angular ASP.NET Core 2.2 Webapplication on VS 2019.

Then i committed this in Azure DevOps & configure the Pipline for manuell or automatic build process which create a docker image. 
After then i create a Docker file in VS2019 -> Project -> ADD Docker Support -> Linux.

Conclusion when i start my pipeline so I get this error

> COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder088029891/WebapplicationTestLinuxDocker/WebapplicationTestLinuxDocker.csproj:
>   no such file or directory /usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1

[image]

Projectstructure: 
[image]

My Docker File looks like: 
[image]

And my .dockerignore have this: 
[image]

I thank you in advance and I hope you can help me! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the source paths are relative to the Dockerfile. So in your Dockerfile it says:

["WebapplicationTestLinuxDocker/WebapplicationTestLinuxDocker.csproj","WebapplicationTestLinuxDocker/"]

change it to:

["WebapplicationTestLinuxDocker.csproj","WebapplicationTestLinuxDocker/"]

then go down two lines and where it says:

COPY . .

change it to:

COPY . WebapplicationTestLinuxDocker/

Hope that works!

Tim

Comment: @azure support/microsoft/visual studio team - This is still broken in latest releases. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Tray this:

```
copy ./path/path path
```

btw I did not see your file in the screenshot :)

Comment: thx for you comment, i try this :)
BTW: i have add my Projectstructure with Docker File :P :P

Comment: can you please explain more about your written text "copy ./path/path path" -> where concret


Generall Question: Do I have two dockerfiles for each frontend & backend ?!? ( I read this often )

Comment: that is a relative path to Dockerfile . normally Docker should run only one service per Container therefore you will find all the good practices refer to seperate each service to its own Container and manage them using docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the docker file on the solution folder level instead of inside the project.